# Magento Model call Resource model function

Tags: magento-1.9

As far as I know, in Resource we put connection with the database, and functions like get one data and this low level stuff.

And in the Model you have more complex functions to get and set data, working with them.

All of this in is a big view. The real problem is:

If I have a function called `getCustom` in the resource, how can i call this function from the model?. I think that I only need `$this->getCustom()`. Both are in the same extension but it doesn't works... why?

My code:

```
config.xml
<custom>
    <class>Example_Name_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>custom_resource</resourceModel>
</custom>
<custom_resource>
    <class>Example_Name_Model_Resource</class>
    <entities>
        <custom>
            <table>example_custom</table>
        </custom>
    </entities>
</custom_resource>

model
class Example_Name_Model_Custom extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    [...]
    public function firstFunction() {
        $this->getCustom();
    }
    [...]

Resource
class Example_Name_Model_Resource_Custom extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    [...]
    public function getCustom()
    {
        return 'Eureka';
    [...]
```

Regards

UPDATE
Maybe the problem is in the construct

```
Model
protected function _construct() {
    $this->_init('custom/custom');
}

ResourceModel
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('custom_resource/custom', 'customer_id');
    // I tried $this->_init('custom/custom', 'customer_id'); too
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your resource functions like this:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('custom_resource/custom')->getCustom();
```

or

```
$this->getCollection()->getCustom(); //This can be called when you are in same module,
//I believe this is what you are looking for.
```

Now, why you cannot call `$this->getCustom()` in model?

You can see model class and resource classes are totally different in magento and they extend different classes too. Because of object oriented programming we can only call parent class function in child class.

For more info you can take a look here: `abstract class Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`

```
/**
 * Get collection instance
 *
 * @return object
 */
public function getResourceCollection()
{
    if (empty($this->_resourceCollectionName)) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Model collection resource name is not defined.'));
    }
    return Mage::getResourceModel($this->_resourceCollectionName, $this->_getResource());
}

public function getCollection()
{
    return $this->getResourceCollection();
}
```

Comment: $resource = Mage::getResourceModel(custom_resource/custom');

 var_dump(get_class($resource));

returns null